# Why is it not possible to remove an upvote without giving a downvote

Tags: feature-request, bug

If you have second thoughts about an upvote, why is it not possible to simply remove it? Removing it now results in a downvote. It seems the algorithm is being too clever. Why not just decrement by one?

I would consider this a design flaw, if the behavior is intentional.

Comment: This really should be asked on the SE meta site. I'm pretty sure it's a site-wide "feature".

Comment: Will do.................

Comment: I don't have that same experience - I can remove up-votes simply by clicking the button again. After a certain period of time you can't change your up-vote unless a post is edited - is that what you ran up against? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30557/cancel-a-vote-so-that-the-tally-goes-back-to-zero-and-not-minus

Comment: @ColleenV No. When I tried to remove an upvote by clicking the down arrow, it changed the answer's rep from +1 to -1.  It should have changed it to 0. Are you clicking the up arrow also to remove it, like a toggle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two buttons are a little unintuitive because they aren't up/down controls for the score, they are two independent buttons: "add up-vote" and "add down-vote". Because you are only allowed one vote per post, adding an up-vote replaces any existing down-vote (and vice versa). It doesn't "remove" it.

To remove an up-vote or down-vote, click the same button again as a toggle. You can only reverse a vote within a set period of time - after that period, you can only change your vote if the post has been edited.

See: [Cancel a vote so that the tally goes back to zero and not minus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30557/cancel-a-vote-so-that-the-tally-goes-back-to-zero-and-not-minus)

Comment: I did not intuit it to be sure.

Comment: It's the positioning of the buttons and the shape - if they were side by side and used a different arrow shape, it might be a little easier to notice how they work.